# speaker name and action in direct speech

Tags: writing

I am trying to write a story in English, though English is not my mother language.

I would like to know if any of the two following lines is correct, and which is better:

"I talked to Bob," said Alice, "and he told me he is happy."

"I talked to Bob," Alice said, "and he told me he is happy."

Answer (score 2):

Both versions are fine. *Said Alice* is the most usual, but many writers like to add variety if the conversation is a long one by sometimes using different ones such as *Alice said, Alice replied* or, for a question, *Alice asked/asked Alice.*

Comment: I think the question here is about the inversion, "said Alice" vs. "Alice said". That is, even if a writer chooses "replied" or "asked", then still it's a very strong convention to end quotes with an inverted statement, e.g. "blah blah blah blah blah", exclaimed Alice.  The example shown in the OP is a bit unusual, though, since the narration (said Alice) breaks the quote, so it might be a good stylistic choice to remove the inversion (which typically comes at the end). This would make it clearer if you read it outloud, that the quote is continuing and that Alice is still the one speaking.

Comment: @Brandin - I thought I had made it clear that the inverted form was perfectly acceptable with any verb of speech.